# how to write to .txt file with orders number

Tags: java

I'm suppose to write orders to file. for an example if there was an order in file and its order number 1 and then when user add another order and hit save, the order will save to .txt file as order number 2 for that date. but my fileWriter written to file in the same line as order number 1.   please take a look at my DaoImpl. thanks.

```
private void writeOrder(LocalDate date) throws OrderPersistenceException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(getFilePath(date)));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new OrderPersistenceException("file");
    }

    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(orderMap.values());

    for (Order currentOrderList : orderList) {

        out.print(currentOrderList.getOrderNumber() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getCustomerName() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getState() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getTaxRate() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getProductType() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getArea() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getCostPerSquareFoot() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getLaborCostPerSquareFoot() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getMeterialCost() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getTotalTax() + DELIMITER
                + currentOrderList.getTotal());

        out.flush();
    }

    out.close();
}

public void saveWork(LocalDate date) throws OrderPersistenceException, IOException {
    writeOrder(date);

}

@Override
public Order addOrder(Order order) throws OrderPersistenceException {
    long orderNumber = ordernumberIncrease(order);
    Order newOrder = orderMap.put(orderNumber, order);

    return newOrder;

}

public Long ordernumberIncrease(Order order) {
    long orderNumber = orderNumInc++;
    order.setOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    return orderNumber;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: i reduced it. hopefully still not too much. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update writeOrder method:

In for loop of use out.println instead of out.print - then each order will start at new line.

Comment: WOW Thank you. i did not saw that. i was so bump and exhausted my searching skill.  problem solve! Thanks

Comment: one more quick question if you wouldn't mind. im running to another issue where the printwrite over written the existing file after the program restart instead of continue write to the next line. should there be an IF statement in the writeOrder method?  Thanks